# How do I search under multiple folders under the global search option(ctrl + shift + f) of Qt creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am working on a project in Qt. The source code directory contains several .cpp, .h, .json, .xml etc. files.

Now, when I use the Qt creator search feature (using ctrl + shift + f) to find a string, I need to specify the scope of search by choosing a directory path in the Directory field of search box as shown in the image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zctzr.png)

Since, the sourcecode is huge, it takes a long time for the machine to go through all the files(matching the file pattern) to find the matching "string".

I already know a set of directories(6 - 7) where the "string" I am looking for might be present in one or more files(I can specify the type of files in the file pattern).

Is there any way to specify only the directories I want to search in the Directory field of the Search option?

Corollarily, Is there any way to exclude one or more directory from the search under a parent directory?

Answer (score 0):

At least as of Qt Creator 3.5, there's no way to specify multiple directories in the search. This would be easy to add, though: Qt Creator is open source, after all :)

Comment: Easy as childbirth